# How to update table2 with table1's id only on a unique match

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

table 1 with id, firstname and lastname

table 2 with t1_id, firstname and lastname

I'd like a SQL query (if possible, not a PL/SQL) to update table2 with table1's id when I have a unique match on firstname and lastname

the word "unique" here is my problem :

```
update table2 t2
set t1_id = (select id from table1 t1
    where t1.firstname=t2.lastname and t1.lastname=t2.lastname)
```

Whenever I have a match from t2 to multiple t1 records, I get the "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" error.
Any clue to not update on multiple matches?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge into table2 d
using (
  select firstname, lastname, max(id) id
  from table1 t1
  group by firstname, lastname
  having count(0) = 1
) s
on (d.firstname=s.firstname and d.lastname=s.lastname)
when matched then update set t1_id = s.id;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I chose this as the solution because 1st, it works ;-) and 2nd, I learned a new MERGE SQL keyword!

Comment: Hi, I have still a problem. Now I have "duplicates" in the table2 (same firstname and lastname) and Oracle says "SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables". Is there a way to improve the USING clause? or add a WHERE clause to filter table2 records? Thanks.

Comment: It should work fine with duplicates in table2.  Can you reproduce your error with simple data example on sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

An inner join would work (For at least SQL Server).

```
update  t1
set t1.id = t2.id 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.firstname=t2.firstname and t1.lastname=t2.lastname
```

Comment: I didn't notice the tag, I will denote this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be to count the matching rows :

```
update table2 t2
set t1_id = 
            (
             select id 
             from table1 t1
             where t1.firstname=t2.lastname and t1.lastname=t2.lastname
            )
where 
(
 select count(*) 
 from table1 
 where t1.firstname = lastname and t1.lastname= lastname
) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the id to NULL in case you find duplicate entries or no entries at all in table1 then simply:

```
update table2 t2
set t1_id = 
(
  select case when min(id) = max(id) then min(id) else null end
  from table1 t1
  where t1.firstname=t2.lastname and t1.lastname=t2.lastname
)
```